# dovecot does not fetch emails to my client

Tags: dovecot

After a considerable amount of struggle I was finally able to set up my email server and connect the account with the client.

Now I am able to send the email from the client but I do not receive any email there.

my dovecot.conf:

```
mail_location = maildir:~/Mail:INBOX=~/Mail/Inbox:LAYOUT=fs
```

if you need anything else, let me know. How can I fix this?

Comment: [Server Fault is a site for information technology professionals](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) -- as such we have certain professional expectations when people ask a question here, and one of those expectations is that your question shows you did some **research**, found and **read the vendor documentation** and/or **tried a solution** before asking the internet for help. You're not expected to solve everything yourself, but then at least you can [write a great question](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) that we can help you answer.

Comment: If you only set the mail_location you probably did not do enough serverside.

Comment: Running en e-mail server on the internet is a non-trivial task, and a lot can go wrong, costing you lots of money when spammers abuse your server. Your question suggests that you do not have any experience with this (dovecot does not receive email from other servers, first of all). It might be a good idea to reconsider if you really should be doing this, or if you are better off using an e-mail service run by an experienced admin. Possibly your server hosting provider also offers e-mail hosting.

Comment: I have set up everything, including postfix, dkim, dmarc, spf, dns, rdns. I think I have done all the steps and I said I can send emails using both 'mail' command and my client. Somehow dovecot does not fetch it. This is only one line from dovecot.conf, do you need the entire config?

Comment: The amount of information in your question is like *“My car is blue. When I turn the key it doesn’t start“* how on earth could I tell you the equivalent of *“you forgot to put petrol in the tank“* or *“the battery is dead”* or *“well, since you’re driving a Jaguar you need to press start”* based on the limited information or rather absence of information that you provide. - Please: Read the link on how to ask a question that we can actually answer that I posted earlier. Providing too much information is almost impossible but just saying “it isn’t working” (as I want it to) really is not enough

Comment: Okay, I am able to read my sent emails in my server in ~/Mail/Sent/cur but I cannot get any emails. Where should I start looking for a glitch ?